# WebDriver versus Apache HTTP Client

Tags: webdriver, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to write some tests which will fire off some HTTP requests to make sure I can login to my app, see some pages etc.

Are my better off using Apache HTTP client or WebDriver?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used both, and I personally prefer WebDriver, because it is more powerful (and easy to use, IMO).

HttpClient won't be able to press a button, run javascript, or other browser functions.

However, if you are looking to make a bunch of HTTP requests, Apache HTTP client will perform them faster.